# Closing mp4 video in python

Tags: python, windows

I have opened a mp4 video stored in my local via (Python code)

```
os.startfile('C:\\Users\\Documents\\Docs\\Acces DSAR.mp4')
```

is there any way to close this video once it is played completely

Comment: so there is no way I can close the mp4 video ?

Comment: No, you have to close the video player manually.